# R - Why does rep() seemingly change behaviour of lists

Tags: r, list, rep

When I started to preinitialize lists of list in R which should be filled afterwards I wondered about the behaviour of list objects when used as value in rep(). When I am trying the following...

```
listOfLists <- rep(list(1, 2), 4)
```

... listOfLists is a single list:

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

However, I would assume it to be a list of lists which finally contain the values 1 and 2 each:

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
```

To get the desired result I have to surround the value entries with c() additionally:

```
listOfLists <- rep(list(c(1, 2)), 4)
```

I wonder why this is the case in R. Shouldn't list create a fully functional list as it normally does instead of doing something similar to c()? Why does grouping the values with c() actually solves the problem here?

Thank you for your thoughts!

---

**Conclusion:**
Both Ben Bolker's and Peyton's posts give the final answer. It was the behaviour of neither the list()- nor the c()-function. Instead rep() seems to combine the entries of lists and vectors to one. Surrounding the values with another container makes rep() actualy "ignore" the first but repeat the second container.

Comment: I don't quite understand your edit, so I assume you are wrong. There is nothing funny about `rep`: it replicates what you give it. Only you seem to miss the difference between `list(1, 2)`, `list(c(1, 2))`, or `list(list(1, 2))`. These are indeed three different objects to start with.

Comment: As Ben Bolker pointed out with the function manual reference "rep replicates the values in x": rep takes the values within the given list/container and repeats them. I thought it would just simply repeat the given list/container as it is inputted into the rep()-function. So it was actually the way rep() works what confused me a short while ago, not the lists or vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does create a fully functional list. The difference is that in your first example, you create a list with two elements, whereas in the second example, you create a list with one element--a vector.

When you combine lists (e.g., with `rep`), you're essentially creating a new list with all the elements of the previous lists. In the first example, then, you'll have eight elements, and in the second example, you'll have four.

Another way to see this:

```
> length(list(1, 2))
[1] 2
> c(list(1, 2), list(1, 2), list(1, 2))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 2

[[5]]
[1] 1

[[6]]
[1] 2

> length(list(1:2))
[1] 1
> c(list(1:2), list(1:2), list(1:2))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: So, essentially what rep does is combining all repeated values to one set. If I would just repeat lists of 1 and 2 from the example, it stitches them together. However, by adding one additional level of container hierarchie, rep() repeats these new containers with their values inside which does the trick, no matter of the new containers are lists or vectors or something of similar functionality. Thank you, I think I finally got it.

Answer (score 4):

What you got with `rep(list(c(1, 2)), 4)` is *not* a list of lists; it's a list of numeric vectors.  If you really want a list of lists, try

```
replicate(4,list(1,2),simplify=FALSE)
```

or

```
rep(list(list(1, 2)), 4)
```

You can understand a *little* bit better why this works as it does by [performing exegesis on](http://archshrk.com/to-exegesis-or-exegete) the first line of `?rep`:

> ‘rep’ replicates the values in ‘x’.

In other words, it promises to replicate the *contents* of `x`, but not necessarily to replicate `x` itself.  (This is why the second suggestion, kindly contributed by @flodel, works -- it makes `x` into a list whose *contents* are a list -- and why the vector-based `rep()` works -- the contents of the list are a vector.)

Comment: This is a good hint of how to get a true list of lists. However, the main question remains: Why does c(1, 2) does the trick in this particular case when list(1, 2) should always create a list as it does when not used in rep().

Comment: I chose Peytons answer now as the final solution but thanks for completing yours as well.